# Does Karma punishment vary according to one's material nature and Ignorance?

Tags: karma, caste-system, animals

- Karma for **killing a Brahmin** is given **punishment higher** than other Varnas.
- This is because Brahmins are of **Sattva guna in dominant manner** than others Varnas.
  **EXAMPLE :**
  Lord Ram got Dosha for Killing Ravana as he was Brahmin(Paulastiya) by Birth
- Gunas reflect one's ignorance level(High Sattva has low ignorance and low sattva has high Ignorance)
- Animals, plants, insects are of high Level of ignorance than Humans

**MY QUESTION:**

- Does Karma punishment vary with material nature and ignorance(**Killing a Brahmin and killing an animal**) ?
- If Karma varies with ignorance then killing animals will cause punishment at low level?

Comment: @@Sakthi Your question is not very clear to me..Killing a Brahmin (if he is like a brahmin) is more sinful than killing a Kshatriya and so on..Killing a human is more sinful than killing an animal(except possibly a cow)..also killing animals with bones are more sinful than killing those which are without bones..Given all that what is ur question exactly now?

Comment: @Rickross friend i was to ask if life form with ignorance level low is killed it has more effect(brahmin has low ignorance level) when compared to life form with high ignorance level(Animals has high ignorance level) then karma punishment for killing life forms vary with thier ignorance level (Killing a brahmin high punishment and killing animal low punishment)  OR NOT ?

Comment: Yes . The same sin committed by two people of two different varnas invites different levels of punishment. The higher the varna the greater the reward and respect ; also the greater the punishment for flouting dharma. Punishment also varies according to age and gender.

Comment: Sakthi-Ok i think i am yet to understand the Q fully..suppose a brahmin kills a deer and a sudra kills a deer..are u asking , since sudra has more ignorance level, will he get a more severe punishment than the brahmin or its the other way round ?

Comment: @Rickross No friend I am asking If punishment for Killing a brahmin By Me OR You Or Anyone and Animals varies due to thier Ignorance Level then Killing Animal causes low karma than brahmin or Not

Comment: Yes killing animals is definitely a lesser sin than killing brahmins..

Comment: @Rickross thanks friend please answer with scriptures and answer also WHY SIN IS LESS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> @Rickross thanks friend please answer with scriptures and answer also
> WHY SIN IS LESS ?

This can be easily understood. In fact killing any human being is a greater sin than killing animals unless we are talking about the cows which are considered as very sacred.

First of all, the Scriptures say that, one who commits sins has the two options to choose form. Either do the necessary atonement ( Prayaschitta ) or face the consequences in the hells.

And, after the terms in hells are complete the soul again gets appropriate bodies depending on the remnant karma that it still has.

> 1. Now after having suffered the torments inflicted in the hells, the evil-doers pass into animal bodies.
>
> **2. Criminals in the highest degree enter the bodies of all plants successively.**
>
> 3. Mortal sinners enter the bodies of worms or insects.
> 4. Minor offenders enter the bodies of birds.
> 5. Criminals in the fourth degree enter the bodies of aquatic animals.
> 6. Those who have committed a crime effecting loss of caste, enter the bodies of amphibious animals.
> 7. Those who have committed a crime degrading to a mixed caste, enter the bodies of deer.
> 8. Those who have committed a crime rendering them unworthy to receive alms, enter the bodies of cattle.
> 9. Those who have committed a crime causing defilement, enter the bodies of (low-caste) men (such as Kandâlas), who may not be touched.
> 10. Those who have committed one of the miscellaneous crimes, enter the bodies of miscellaneous wild carnivorous animals (such as tigers)
>
> **Vishnu Smriti, Chapter XLIV .**

So, we can easily identify the pattern being followed here.

The highest degree sinners are getting born in plant bodies, ( which have the lowest degree of awareness or consciousness among all living beings )  relatively lesser sinners get insect bodies, animal bodies and so on depending on the degree of bad karmas.

Human bodies are however obtained very very rarely when the karmas are more on the merit side . So, the soul which is being born as a human being, for example, has more punya karma (merit) than the one which is being born as an animal.

Hence, going by this logic we can say that killing a plant is a lesser sin than killing an animal. Because the highest degree sinners are getting born as plants.

And, this is also the reason why a plant based diet is preferred over an animal based one with the former incurring lesser bad karmas than the later.

So, by the same logic,  killing an animal will also be a lesser sin than killing a human being.

The thing to understand here is that the greater the degree of sins, the lower the awareness or consciousness levels of the being into which the soul is getting born.